# Support for fallback sources with Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Currently `asp-fallback-test-class` only works with singular classes:

```
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    asp-fallback-test-class="hidden"
    asp-fallback-test-property="visibility"
    asp-fallback-test-value="hidden" />
```

How can I test files with multiple selectors? For examples:

- [dataTables.bootstrap.css](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css) has at bare minimum two selectors chained together like `table.dataTable { ... }` but no standalone `.dataTable` class.
- Similarly with [skin-red.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.0/css/skins/skin-red.css), there are only descendant selectors like `.skin-red .main-header .navbar { ... }` and again no standalone `.skin-red` class.

There is also a [workaround](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580#issuecomment-339963438):

> Probably the best way around this is to fork, add a test class (like `.skin-red-fallback-test { ... }`) within the individual file, then make a PR for whichever particular library one might be using.

But I don't know what he meant by making a PR. Could someone explain for me please?

Comment: PR = Pull Request in Git (especially GitHub Repository). It's when you done some changes to the source code and want to contribute these back to the original project [GitHub: About Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)

Comment: It basically means, you should modify the targeted css file to add a dummy css class, which is used for the testing. This however won't work if you get your css files via package manager (npm, bower) hence the suggest to add it to the source code and contribute it back to the original project, so in the next release its also included in the packages shipped via npm/bower and at some point that it allows the cdn hosted (link the ones you linked above) to have such a dummy class too